# PHP: passing an xml node to function

Tags: php, xml, function, iteration

i'm trying to pass an xml node to a function but can't figure out how - here's my xml markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<root>
<form>
<item>
    <id>frm1</id>
    <dbID>1</dbID>
    <visible>1</visible>
</item>
</form>
<form>
<item>
    <id>frm2</id>
    <dbID>2</dbID>
    <visible>1</visible>
</item>
</form>
</root>
```

when setting up a foreach loop - how's the syntax to iterate through the xml and passing the whole  node to a function?
i've tried something like:

```
foreach($xml as $ctlXML => $value)
{
    $ctl = generateCTL($ctlXML);
}
```

but it doesn't work as it should.

thanks

Comment: You should show us a bit more code, like how you load the XML *(simplexml ? DOM ?)*, how you call the function, what you get, and what you'd want to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SimpleXML it is simple as

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($path_to_file);
foreach($xml->form as $form){
    $ctl = generateCTL($form->item);
}
```

Be careful - $form->item is an object

Comment: It should be `foreach($xml->form as $form)`